# Showing that $X = int(A) \cup Fr(A)\cup int(X-A)$

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $A\subset X$. Show that $X = int(A) \cup Fr(A)\cup int(X-A)$, this being a union disjointed.

To show this equality I must show the inclusions:
\begin{equation}
X \subseteq int(A) \cup Fr(A)\cup int(X-A)
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
int(A) \cup Fr(A)\cup int(X-A)\subseteq X
\end{equation}

Picking up a point $x$ from $X$ and showing that it's in $int(A) \cup Fr(A)\cup int(X-A)$. And vice versa?
Is that what it was?

Answer (score 4):

Let $x\in X$ be arbitrary and let $\mathcal N_x$ denote its set of neighborhoods.

Purely on logical grounds we can say that exactly one of the following options is correct:

- $\exists N\in\mathcal N_x [N\subseteq A]$
- $\exists N_x\in\mathcal N_x [N\subseteq A^\complement]$
- $\forall N\in\mathcal N_x [N\cap A\neq\varnothing\text{ and }N\cap A^{\complement}\neq\varnothing]$

This can be rephrased as:

- $x\in\mathsf{int}(A)$
- $x\in\mathsf{int}(A^{\complement})$
- $x\in\mathsf{Fr}(A)$

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

The second inclusion comes for free, since $X$ is the topological space you're working in, so every set you're treating is a subset of $X$.

The other needs a little more work.  If you don't know where to start, try drawing $A$ on a piece of paper, and delimiting clearly what are $\text{int}(A)$, $\text{fr}(A)$, and $\text{int}(X-A)$ :).

Comment: I keep thinking like this: if I take a point in $X$, there are $3$ options or it is in $int(A)$ or is in $Fr(A)$ or is in $int(A-X)$ . And with that I've already stifuded that he's in the union. And strange, is that correct?

Comment: That is the why to think about it indeed. You just need to be careful when justifying that it **has** to be in one of those three :). *Hint:* look at the definition of the frontier of $A$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\operatorname{Int}(A)\sqcup\operatorname{Fr(A)}=\operatorname{cl}(A)$, which is (by definition? I guess it depends on your definition of closure and boundary of a subset) the smallest closed subset of $X$ containing $A$.

This way, you just have to show that $X=\operatorname{cl}(A)\,\sqcup\,\operatorname{Int}(X\smallsetminus A)$; but again, $\operatorname{Int}(X\smallsetminus A)$ is (by definition) the largest open subset of $X$ *contained* in $X\smallsetminus A$.

Considering this, you can easily find that $\operatorname{Int}(X\smallsetminus A)=X\smallsetminus\operatorname{cl}(A)$, which leads us to what you're trying to prove. (Notice that all unions here are disjoint!)